# Javascripts run properly only after the first time the page loads in Google Chrome 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, google-chrome

If you use chrome 4 going to this page: http://web.cara-jo.net/

You will find that the slideshow does not run for the first time.

Then if you reload the page, you will magically find that the slideshow runs properly.

The slideshow is a jquery plugin called Pikachoose: http://pikachoose.com/

What makes such an interesting behaviour in chrome 4?

I have tried to load the same page in IE8 and Firefox 3.6, both do not have this problem.

Comment: Seems to work properly for me.
First time loading the page, looks the same in Chrome 4 (mac) and in FF. Looks the same on subsequent reloads as well

Comment: please post some specifics here.  We have no idea what this plugin might look like or even more specifically, what your implementation looks like.

Comment: is the slideshow supposed to scroll automatically?

Comment: It's strange, it's version 4.0.249.78 for my Chrome (Windows XP).

I don't have any implementation, I just happened to encounter this interesting behaviour when I visited the page.
I also found another page having similar problem with Chrome 4. If you visit http://pikachoose.com/demo/ using Chrome 4, you will see the slideshow doesn't load, but it loads successfully in Firefox 3.6 and IE8.

There has to be something wrong with Chrome 4, I just haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this problem would pop up randomly across different browsers. If anyone is still having this issue make sure you upgrade PikaChoose (3.2 is out at the time of writing this) and that'll fix it.

~Jeremy, Creator of PikaChoose

Comment: It's nice to have the author to answer this question. Thank you so much for your help.